# Can id_rsa.pub be deleted on the server?

Tags: security, ssh, rsa, public-key

Once id_rsa.pub has been concatenated to a remote server's authorized_keys file, can id_rsa.pub be deleted? Does a copy of the file id_rsa.pub need to reside in the server's .ssh directory? If it is not needed, is it considered a best-practice to keep a copy on the server, or to delete it?

Comment: This is a public key. It's not secure, it's public. You could place it everywhere over the Internet :) But if you'll need it again after deletion, you'll need to generate keys again and reconfigure access at every place you use them.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh If you have a copy of the private key at hand, you can extract the public key from it. ssh-keygen has an option to do it.

Comment: @Kenster Yes, you are right. I ocasionaly thought that `jshock` will delete it too.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the public key from some other computer that has been copied to the server. These are not typically stored on the server, and would be confusing to store there (I generally paste the contents directly into authorized_keys using vim, bypassing the need to copy the file).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read several tutorials that had me copy my public key to the remote server's .ssh directory, then use vim, nano, or cat > to append it to authorized_keys. None of them mention the public key after that. I was just wondering if it was necessary -- or best-practice -- to leave a copy on the server. I try to keep directories clean and delete unnecessary files, unless best-practice is to keep them. I of course keep a local copies of the private & public keys in a secure place.

Comment: As for me, I'd like to have the keys stored in directory rather than keep it clean. Directories are designed to store files.